# How do I pass an "out int" parameter in BizTalk orchestration?

Tags: c#, .net, biztalk, out

I have a method written in C#:

```
public static void MyMethod(string myString, out int myInteger)
...
```

In BizTalk orchestration I am declaring one variable as an int32 and setting it to "0".

When calling the method with this variable I get the following error:

> Cannot convert from 'System.Int32' to 'out System.Int32'

My question: how do I declare an "out int32" in BizTalk Orchestration?

Or how can I manage to call this method that requires an "out int"?

Comment: why not use a return value?

Comment: not sure that I understand what you mean, could you clarify?
Grateful for anything that can solve this.

Comment: `public static int MyMethod(string myString)` where the return value (`int`) is the same as `myInteger`

Comment: Could work, will try it.
I am actually counting fields in a xml-file in this method, so it´s counting up in the variable. Will try it, and get back with response.